# What is the difference between Nullable.GetValueOrDefault() and Nullable.Value?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Are there other scenarios where I need to use one of the following other than what is mentioned?

- `Nullable.GetValueOrDefault()`: If the value is null, you will get null, otherwise the value.
- `Nullable.Value`: If the value is null, an exception will be thrown.
- `Nullable<>.HasValue`: Returns true or false.
- `Nullable<> != null` Same as above.

I was a bit confused because I have seen codes on GitHub check the `HasValue` or `!= null` then return the value if true, otherwise return null. I would rather just use the first. Is there any side-effect or something that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

`Nullable.Value` throws an exception if `Nullable.HasValue` is false. `Nullable.GetValueOrDefault()` returns the type's default value if `Nullable.HasValue` is false.